# Align textarea next to checkbox css bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to align a text area next to a checkbox.

My bootstrap html is:

```
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-12 form-check">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="check15">Filter "na" results</label>
                            <input id="check15" class="box15" type="checkbox">
                            <textarea class="col-3 form-control form-control-sm" rows="5" id="filter_na_results"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

For some reason textarea appears UNDER the row with label and checkbox. How do I make textarea to appear on the right of checkbox in same line with checkbox?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vknec62q/1/) too.

Comment: It's because the textarea is set to display: block. Add the class `d-inline-block` to `<textarea>`

Comment: @elveti this look almost exactly what I need but is aligned with the bottom of textarea. How do I align it with the top?

Comment: you can use vertical-align for that, in Bootstrap they are done with `align-*`. I think you'd need to add `align-top` or `align-middle` to your `<textarea>`. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/ for more options

Comment: @elveti To be honest, I end up going with your pure css solution, if you would make it into the answer I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove form-control class and also remove the div having flex and change it to row. And add align-items-start on the row div to align them to the top of textarea.

Add p-0 class on label

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-12 form-check">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <label class="col-3 col-form-label p-0" for="check15">Filter "na" results</label>
      <input id="check15" class="box15" type="checkbox">
      <textarea class="col-3 form-control-sm offset-3" rows="5" id="filter_na_results"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I align it with the top of textarea? Right now it aligns with the bottom.

Comment: Use align-items-start instead of align-items-end

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-12 form-check">
    <div class="flex">
      <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="check15">Filter "na" results</label>
      <input id="check15" class="box15" type="checkbox">
      <textarea class="col-3 form-control form-control-sm offset-3" rows="5" id="filter_na_results"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost there! I need the label, checkbox and top of textarea to be on same line. I tried to change `align-items` to `top` but it is not exactly on same line but almost what I need. Do you know how to align them precisely?